# How to define a fractal from the lexicographic sorting on the prime factorization of natural numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, fractals

Consider on the natural number the lexicographic ordering on the prime factorization:
If $m = p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r},n = q_1^{b_1}\cdots q_s^{b_s}$ then we define:

$$m \vartriangleleft n :\iff [(p_1,a_1),(p_2,a_2),\cdots,(p_r,a_r)] \prec [(q_1,b_1),(q_2,b_2),\cdots,(q_s,b_s)]$$

where the right hand side $\prec$ is the lexicographic ordering of the two lists, where $(p,a) \prec (q,b) :\iff p < q  \text{ or } ( p=q \text{ and } a < b)$ and the primes in the factorization list are sorted by usual absolute value: $p_i < p_{i+1}$.

Example:

1. For instance for $n=1,\cdots , 10 $ we get the following sorting:

$$1, 2, 6, 10, 4, 8, 3, 9, 5, 7$$

2)

Examples :

sorted by absolute value:  $[2, 7, 11, 30, 60, 121]$

lexicographically sorted:  $[2, 30, 60, 7, 11, 121]$

```
[(2, 1)] = [(2, 1)]
[(2, 1)] < [(7, 1)]
[(2, 1)] < [(11, 1)]
[(2, 1)] < [(2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(2, 1)] < [(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(2, 1)] < [(11, 2)]
[(7, 1)] > [(2, 1)]
[(7, 1)] = [(7, 1)]
[(7, 1)] < [(11, 1)]
[(7, 1)] > [(2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(7, 1)] > [(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(7, 1)] < [(11, 2)]
[(11, 1)] > [(2, 1)]
[(11, 1)] > [(7, 1)]
[(11, 1)] = [(11, 1)]
[(11, 1)] > [(2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(11, 1)] > [(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(11, 1)] < [(11, 2)]
[(2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1)] > [(2, 1)]
[(2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1)] < [(7, 1)]
[(2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1)] < [(11, 1)]
[(2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1)] = [(2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1)] < [(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1)] < [(11, 2)]
[(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1)] > [(2, 1)]
[(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1)] < [(7, 1)]
[(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1)] < [(11, 1)]
[(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1)] > [(2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1)] = [(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1)] < [(11, 2)]
[(11, 2)] > [(2, 1)]
[(11, 2)] > [(7, 1)]
[(11, 2)] > [(11, 1)]
[(11, 2)] > [(2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(11, 2)] > [(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(11, 2)] = [(11, 2)]
```

I used this sorting to visualize the following Jaccard similarty kernel, where $\Omega$ counts the prime divisors with multiplicity:

$$\frac{\Omega(\gcd(a,b))}{\Omega(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b))}$$

where the entries $n=1,\ldots, N=1400$ of the matrix are sorted by the lexicographic ordering above:

[image: prime_factorization_fractal_with_lexicographi_sorting]

**Q: While there seems to be some visual fractal pattern, I am asking myself, how does one quantify / define this fractal pattern?**

One idea would be to let $N \rightarrow \infty$ and make the matrix larger, so that one can zoom in but I am not sure how to formalize this idea.

**Edit**:
Here is another image for the kernel $\omega(\gcd(a,b))$ whose Gram matrix of size $n \times n$ has rank $\pi(n)$, where $\omega$ counts the distinct prime divisors of $n$ and $\pi$ is the prime counting function:

[image: prime_factorization_fractal_lexicographic_sorting_omega_kernel]

Counting the size of the blocks on the main diagonal, we find the [following OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A249809):

$$0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1$$

[SageMath-script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJytVk2P2yoU3Y80_4GXFXaYmTjT6knzyltUapfppjvLirBNpshgCDjTyb8vGIPtJJNppUZREuDcr3PPxanpDkhBnwlsk6fbG2BfmnYH3QJOW6g0E3RbsxdmpDYWktze3N7U1ubbRRtzEPCF8APpmGxhi1QCdlIDBVgL3vb1rImATYO0PnEnSKfZK8zzpoEEld4Zcc60LvpFOSyirx2purO0crhH07T2iXe1d9Y2m47W56UiTV-oNhR_JdzQpAgROIUCxQhKAeyDisTv7Pdhp01mWVjoJ3vq_HhPlRSK6Jk7Fv0D0tZA_IPb4WTi6C6LYIEvAVazuMvMBdxpKcDu0FadlNwAJpStG1RCbTu5bejRYegrEYpTYwsYWMnX6F-UZfadpmu0Th_Tj_Yz7X940i1vbQcXX4Lp0yKJm94JKI-AlEbyQ0eBawN9AgsUYo1oTl9ZJa0Y1A9WEc6PQxIOHfIJVgjYlPGYPRy4TLyqok4CfuAoSuZkv-9kn0XfOJKgxafF0IxeeNRKACxwv0cwLoeN_21mvUXp4w6sWt0qLjvOyvtK_Ad8x33PNanP5Km0vKC_KOmmyfokRok8V3W_g3H2XvP9nAaD5MGveSX8GoxB1tMgg7WcW4_gxwvgdRqAafr4AElappAsZ2YfLphlD46TiH6YOElG3mxzO7N1It4qO5hMHgwMP2bj01pS-tkJpxjnxTlLeVZEE2a2PftjY7wevP09UYq2NcyGaXadn8DctAt2-aoMmMZi_LlicJ-cx8ibYomzE1H4I7c1IwGeVnulOM5t5HxVpDCGb5NlqIRze2QB2TgcTX-fkvaZwjVqLXJKyOVKm2ml1mWMpGyku-ysMM7jLNDqpKL-kqqkOob7qaZU9WtiQK3eKzsvios90i71WsEx4F02zfpNDXjjoIC8mNichPhdKVyVQ8-yyzXQcpqJ1QmORSi3nD9ibKG9XIKFY7px4ex4-8t6EJVVReGvyc3Y8QytY8MnyKujt0kC3t2eGxQOZtsx5U2gQhw5M5117r5gCL9ZxrYYFxkOt75HX73zx2AmxrZXMPyma6pp_V1TOksjuTc_5E84hYa_IdYBqiSXuiQaf9cHiipBFF58tk8us0DEKFp1W-3-TOBs8FMrhrPVanDnqN64wVqt_DKyM7JwlYE_rf6v5L-ZPM-JqRjb2mzfJjD5Bd437Fs=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: How is the factorization ordered? Are the primes in increasing order? The prime powers? Something else?

Comment: @CommandMaster: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer my question based on my findings so far:

First, I will slightly change the definition of $\trianglelefteq$ without changing the fractal appereance of the image much:

If $m = p_1 p_2 \cdots p_r$ and $n = q_1 q_2 \cdots q_s$ are the decompositions of $m,n$ in prime factors with repetitions allowed and $p_i \le p_{i+1}$ then we define $m \trianglelefteq n$ as :

$$m \trianglelefteq n :\iff (p_1,\cdots,p_r) \le (q_1,\cdots,q_s)$$

where the right hand side is the lexicographic ordering which coincides with the usual ordering on tuples of length one.

Let us look at the matrix $m_{a,b}$ defined by $m_{a,b} = 1$ if $\gcd(a,b)>1$ and $0$ otherwise, where the numbers $1,\cdots,n$ are sorted by $\trianglelefteq$. Plotting this matrix for some large number, we get the following picture:

[image: fractal_prime_numbers]

To explain the visually perceived self-similarity, let me introduce for each natural number $n$, a factorization tree $T_n$ as follows:

Let $P_1(n) := 1$ if $n=1$ and $\max_{q|n, \text{ }q\text{ prime}} q$ otherwise, denote the largest prime divisor of $n$.

Let us define some rooted trees $T_{n,m}$ for $1 \le m \le n$ by:

1. $T_{n,m}$ has as root the number $m$.
2. If there are primes $p$ such that $P_1(m) \le p \le \frac{n}{m}$, then the children of $m$ are $T_{n,mp}$, otherwise $m$ is a leaf.

We set $T_n := T_{n,1}$.

Here are some examples of these tree:

[image: Factorization_tree_N=10]

[image: Factorization_tree_N=25]

[image: Factorization_tree_N=99]

These trees can also be defined by successively puttting the node $n+1$ into the tree $T_n$ to get the rooted and ordered tree $T_{n+1}$, if one knows the prime factorization of $n+1$. The tree has the following property:

Sorting the nodes by pre-order, we get the same ordering as $\trianglelefteq$.

Furthermore, by this definition, we see that the tree has some self-similar property, which explains some of the visually perceived self-similarity on the image.

Also notice that the blocks on the main diagonal of the blue fractal image have size $a_p(n)$ equal to the sizes of the smaller subtrees in the recursive definition.